# Do +Meteor damage and Nilfur's Boast boots affect Tal Rasha Meteors?

Tags: diablo-iii

I can't seem to find any consensus...

Tal Rasha's bonus rains down meteors from the sky when you hit with an elemental attack. I've been trying to see if the meteors called down from Tal Rasha procs are affected by +Meteor damage affixes on gear as well as the +100% from the Nilfur's Boast boots (and the extra bonus for # of enemies hit).

Anyone know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Builds (at least the ones I find on [/r/Diablo3](https://www.reddit.com/r/diablo3) and [/r/Diablo3Wizards](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo3Wizards)) are actually centered around just these.

As someone currently running that exact build (On PS4, so I cannot link bnet profile), I can tell you that both +Meteor damage and Nilfur boots absolutely do boost the effect. I got my Nilfur boots after completing my Tal Rasha's set, and saw a decent increase in damage. Additional information from the above reddit sub-forums as well as the Diablo 3 forums confirms this.

As far as I can tell, the proc from Tal Rasha's set behaves as if you had cast the meteor yourself with the appropriate element.

Comment: I'd like supporting numbers, too. I'd recommend holding out for another answer that can provide something more solid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running with Tal Rasha's and got the whole set, and yes, they are using the +Meteor bonus from items, as well as the 100% from the boots.

Here's a guide to the build, and a good documentation on it: [icy-veins.com](http://www.icy-veins.com/d3/wizard-fire-build-with-the-tal-rasha-set-patch-2-2)

Here's a little snippet from it, regarding your question:

> Introduced in Patch 2.2, the new best friend of the Tal Rasha set are the Nilfur's Boast boots. Doubling the damage of Meteors by default, and with the potential to triple your Meteor damage against three or less enemies, these boots are non-negotiable for a Tal Rasha Wizard. Naturally, seek out Meteor % bonus alongside the usual primary stats.

But as @Thebluefish says, take a look on [/r/Diablo3](http://www.reddit.com/r/diablo) and [/r/Diablo3Wizards](http://www.reddit.com/r/diablo3wizards) for more info om builds, and setups.